# Question on probability and the application of standard deviation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, standard-deviation

this is a question on probability which is new to me so I'd appreciate it if someone would tell me why my answers are wrong.

---

> Suppose $10\%$ of all wine bottles have corks (instead of screw-tops).
>   A restaurant opens $400$ random bottles in a month and counts the
>   number that are corked. Use a normal distribution to estimate the
>   probability that the restaurant will open $k$ corked bottles.
>
> (a) What are μ and σ in the normal approximation?

The standard deviation is the average, so it would be $40$ corked bottles. σ is just the standard deviation squared, so that'd be $40^2$.

> (b) The probability is about .68 that the number of corked bottles
>   will fall between a and b. What are a and b?

Since 68% percent falls between one standard deviation, wouldn't this be $80$?

> (c) What are a and b for an approximate probability of .95?

This is two standard deviations, so $160$.

> (d) What are a and b for an approximate probability of .99?

Three standard deviations, so $240$.

> The restaurant wants the head waiter to avoid serving corked bottles
>   since they’re more expensive. So they offer her a bonus if fewer than
>   the expected number of corked bottles gets opened, provided the
>   results are significant at the .01 level. On the other hand they’ll
>   fire her if more than the expected number of corked bottles gets
>   opened, assuming the results are significant at the .01 level.
>
> (e) How few corked bottles have to be opened for the head waiter to
>   get the bonus? How many corked bottles have to opened for the head
>   waiter to lose her job? (Assume the estimates above are accurate.)

I don't get this question, wouldn't this just be the opposite of a standard deviation at 99%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (a), just think about how ridiculous the answer seems. $40^2=1600$, meaning that samples are an average of 1600 bottles away from the true mean, when there are only 400 in the population. $\sigma$ is not the standard deviation squared, IT IS the standard deviation. Therefore, $\sigma$ is the $variance$ squared, which is given by $\sigma=\sqrt{npq}$, where $n$ is the sample size, $q=1-p$, and $p$ is the probability of a success.

For (b), you are correct in stating that $0.68$ is within one standard deviation of the mean, but you initial calculation of standard deviation is incorrect. Again, $\sigma=Standard Deviation=\sqrt{npq}$. This means that $a=\mu-\sigma$ and $b=\mu+\sigma$.

For (c), $.95$ is 2 standard deviations away from the mean, but again, your standard deviation is incorrect. $a=\mu-2\sigma$ and $b=\mu+2\sigma$.

For (d), same as (b) and (c), but $a=\mu-3\sigma$ and $b=\mu+3\sigma$.

For (e), since .01 is the significance level, having less than the $1st$ percentile (in bottles) opened means she gets a bonus, and having more than the $99th$ percentile gets her fired.

Comment: Does that mean $\mu = 40$ and $\sigma = 6$?

Comment: Well, I didn't take the time to calculate $\sigma$ myself, but I'm assuming that's right. As for $\mu$, that is correct.

Comment: As for (e) does this mean the answer for both is one reversed? The $1^{st}$ percentile would be the answer to d (between 22 and 58) but how does that make sense since it gives two answers?

Comment: One of the answers gives you the condition such that she gets a raise, and the other gives the condition such that she gets fired.